# Filter MDX, SQL Server and Analysis Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have query like this one:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    [DIM CUSTOMER].[Country Region Code].[Country Region Code].ALLMEMBERS
}
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY CROSSJOIN( {
    [DIM PRODUCT].[Category Name].CHILDREN
}, 
{
    [DIM PRODUCT].[Sub Category Name].CHILDREN
})
ON ROWS FROM [Foo]
WHERE (
     [Measures].[Order Qty]
);
```

now I would like to add filtering, basically include only categories and subcategories where at least 10 different products were sold.
I end up with sth like below, but it returns nothing...

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    [DIM CUSTOMER].[Country Region Code].[Country Region Code].ALLMEMBERS
}
ON COLUMNS, 
FILTER (
CROSSJOIN( {
    [DIM PRODUCT].[Category Name].CHILDREN
}, 
{
    [DIM PRODUCT].[Sub Category Name].CHILDREN
},
{ [DIM PRODUCT].[Name].CHILDREN
}),
    [DIM PRODUCT].[Name].CHILDREN.COUNT > 0
) 
ON ROWS FROM [Foo]
WHERE (
     [Measures].[Order Qty]
);
```

If someone is so proficient that it wouldn't take him 40 minutes to spot mistake like me, please help & thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.CHILDREN` you may need `.members`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe swap this:

```
[DIM PRODUCT].[Name].CHILDREN.COUNT > 0
```

For this:

```
[DIM PRODUCT].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN.COUNT > 0
```